# Flask profling error: the profiler is not available because profile or pstat is not installed

Tags: python, flask, profiling, werkzeug, pstats

I'm attempting to run a profiling process on my website, per the discussion [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-debugging-testing-and-profiling), but have run into this error. Here's the full stack trace:

```
C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\python.exe C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/mysite/profile.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/mysite/profile.py", line 6, in <module>
    app = ProfilerMiddleware(app)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\envs\mysite\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\contrib\profiler.py", line 80, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('the profiler is not available because '
RuntimeError: the profiler is not available because profile or pstat is not installed.
```

At first I assumed that this is one of those Windows errors, and I tried doing the same thing on my Mac. Same error.

Hmm. I found the [responsible import statements](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/contrib/profiler.py#L22) in the `werkzeug` code:

```
try:
    try:
        from cProfile import Profile
    except ImportError:
        from profile import Profile
    from pstats import Stats
    available = True
except ImportError:
    available = False
```

This causes the failure on later on, on [line 79](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/contrib/profiler.py#L79):

```
    if not available:
        raise RuntimeError('the profiler is not available because '
                           'profile or pstat is not installed.')
```

So I guess that means I'm missing one of these modules? But they're [core Python modules](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/profile.html#module-profile) AFAIK!

I popped open a `IPython` console, booted into the responsible `conda` virtual environment, and sure enough:

[image]

What's going on?